# C# Barrier timeout

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, timeout, barrier

I'm running some tasks in parallel, normally 4 at a time. For one test I need a barrier, so they are synchronized at that point.

The Barrier is then configured like `new Barrier(4);`. The issue is that sometimes, an exception might happen, which could lead the task to stop at a certain point and no longer reaches the Barrier.

This would make the Barrier wait eternally, how can I solve this?
Is it possible to configure a Timeout to release the Barrier, and test the ones that have reached it until that moment?

*[This question is related to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49117255/2641352)*

Comment: It is not the barrier that is the problem, it is your code not handling the exception correctly.  Odds that you can actually handle it are not good, ensure your program bombs loudly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want 3 tasks to continue even if the 4th task has failed. In this case you can use [SignalAndWait(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload to wait for the other participants only for the specified period of time.

Comment: Ups... I should've seen this, I guess I did not associate with the name, thanks. I'll test and accept later

Comment: @miguelmpn sure. Also, if it's not some side-code, but a product, providing appropriate exception handling is probably a much better way then leaving the barrier with timeout.

Comment: It is a project and I'm aware of the root cause, but I must get it working fast and then I will have time to sort out any remaining exceptions and handle them. Either way after an error in a Task, handled or not, in my case the process cannot continue, therefore I end up with this anyway. Thank you for the advice.